# Django ORM repeats DB columns when trying to save()

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm working with an old legacy database, and I'm having trouble with working out the correct way to perform an insert into this database. When I'm trying to save() an object i get SQL error

> CUSTOMER_ID cannot be repeated in INSERT statement

This is caused (I believe) by the way I had to create foreign key connection:

```
customer_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='CUSTOMER_ID') 
tbcustomer = models.ForeignKey(TbCustomer, db_column='CUSTOMER_ID', to_field='customer_id')
```

The customer_id integer field must stay! I know this structure is ugly,  but the database is really old and I'm in no position to change it.

Should I rethink this foreign key implementation, or would it be possible to overcome this error in other way (custom save() method maybe?). Any suggestions are welcome, Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you have repeated the db field. Just remove the IntegerField.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, integer field is in the database (and will be there, used by other software) and this is the only way I've found to implement a foreign key in this database. I cannot change the DB structure itself. The tbcustomer field isnt really a field in a database, it just uses cusomer_id to create a foreign key relationship.

Comment: But a foreign key *is* an integer. You really don't need it twice, and the integerfield does *not* need to stay. You can always set the value via the ForeignKey field. This does not affect the structure of the table at all.

Comment: Now i feel stupid. But I guess that's what I needed. So, to be sure I am able to: entry = Customer(customer_id=123) entry.save(); when customer_id is a ForeignKey field?

Comment: Well, you should call the ForeignKey field itself `customer`, then you can indeed refer to the underlying ID column with `customer_id`.